# Replace one item in a string with one item from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, replace, sequence

I have a string and a list:

`seq = '01202112'`

`l = [(0,1,0),(1,1,0)]`

I would like a pythonic way of replacing each `'2'` with the value at the corresponding index in the list `l` such that I obtain two new strings:

`list_seq = [01001110, 01101110]`

By using `.replace()`, I could iterate through `l`, but I wondered is there a more pythonic way to get `list_seq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this solution is 'more pythonic' but:

```
def my_replace(s, c=None, *other):
        return s if c is None else my_replace(s.replace('2', str(c), 1), *other)


seq = '01202112'
l = [(0,1,0),(1,1,0)]

list_req = [my_replace(seq, *x) for x in l]
```

Answer (score 4):

I might do something like this:

```
out = [''.join(c if c != '2' else str(next(f, c)) for c in seq) for f in map(iter, l)]
```

The basic idea is that we call `iter` to turn the tuples in `l` into iterators.  At that point every time we call `next` on them, we get the next element we need to use instead of the `'2'`.

If this is too compact, the logic might be easier to read as a function:

```
def replace(seq, to_replace, fill):
    fill = iter(fill)
    for element in seq:
        if element != to_replace:
            yield element
        else:
            yield next(fill, element)
```

giving

```
In [32]: list(replace([1,2,3,2,2,3,1,2,4,2], to_replace=2, fill="apple"))
Out[32]: [1, 'a', 3, 'p', 'p', 3, 1, 'l', 4, 'e']
```

Thanks to @DanD in the comments for noting that I had assumed I'd always have enough characters to fill from!  We'll follow his suggestion to keep the original characters if we run out, but modifying this approach to behave differently is straightforward and left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: This will truncate the output if it runs out of fill. To leave it unchanged requires `yield next(fill, element)`

Answer (score 1):

```
[''.join([str(next(digit, 0)) if x is '2' else x for x in seq])
 for digit in map(iter, l)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
seq = '01202112'
li = [(0,1,0),(1,1,0)]

def grunch(s, tu):
    it = map(str,tu)
    return ''.join(next(it) if c=='2' else c for c in s)

list_seq = [grunch(seq,tu) for tu in li]
```